# Daemonize Thread do nothing

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7

I've wrote some lines in order to send some data from AP to an Zabbix Server.(its ok for that thing...)

But, i want to create a daemon-thread for it.
Except that, it won't release my terminal... i can't do anything during his execution. I've tried some tutorial about threading, but nothing revelant for me...

This is my code :

```
def miningBot():
#initialisation dictionnary
    hostIP = {}
    hostIP['Bornes Wifi -- LYON', 'borne5nbHostsLY'] = "*.*.*.*"
    hostIP['Bornes Wifi -- LYON', 'borne6nbHostsLY'] = "*.*.*.*"
    hostIP['Bornes Wifi -- GRENOBLE', 'borne6nbHostsGRE'] = "*.*.*.*"
    hostIP['Bornes Wifi -- GRENOBLE', 'borne7nbHostsGRE'] = "*.*.*.*"
    while True:
        for value, ip in hostIP.items():
            nbHosts = pickaxe(ip)
            zabbix_cmd = "zabbix_sender -z *.*.*.* -p 10051 -s '" + value[0] + "' -k " + value[1] + " -o " + str(nbHosts)
            zabbix_sender = subprocess.check_output(zabbix_cmd, shell=True)
        sleep(10)

t = Thread(target=miningBot)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

Excuse me for my English... and thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daemon threads are threads that are not considered barrier for program termination, ie. when the only running threads are daemon, the program will terminate. They have nothing to do with daemonization so this is not what you want.

You cannot daemonize a single thread, you need to daemonize the whole process to detach it from the terminal. (So you actually don't need any extra thread at all.) You can use [Python Daemon library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon) to do that.